# How to find the average consecutive loss in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, excel-2016

[image]

Is there any way to calculate the average consecutive losses without having the column F? The correct output is 1.75 in this example. Thank you.

Comment: What version of Excel have you got? Also, aren't the first three values three consecutive losses?

Comment: I have 2016 excel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=AVERAGE(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(A1:A12<0,ROW(A1:A12)),IF(A1:A12<0,0,ROW(A1:A12)))=0,"",FREQUENCY(IF(A1:A12<0,ROW(A1:A12)),IF(A1:A12<0,0,ROW(A1:A12)))))
```

Confirm through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

If one has Excel O365, you could also use:

```
=LET(X,FREQUENCY(IF(A1:A12<0,ROW(A1:A12)),IF(A1:A12<0,0,ROW(A1:A12))),AVERAGE(FILTER(X,X>0,"")))
```

---

Note, my answer is two, because the first three values in your example are all negative.

Comment: So does it means that `frequency` function is not the function that only can be used for 365 subscriber? Everyone with excel can use the `frequency` function?

Comment: @Elvis, [`FREQUENCY()`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/frequency-function-44e3be2b-eca0-42cd-a3f7-fd9ea898fdb9) has been around since Excel 2010 =)

Comment: May I know how should I change the formula for the average consecutive win as well? I changed `>` to `<` but it seems like the calculation involve empty cells which result a big average consecutive win      `AVERAGE(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(K64:K313>0,ROW(K64:K313)),IF(K64:K313>0,0,ROW(K64:K313)))=0,"",FREQUENCY(IF(K64:K313>0,ROW(K64:K313)),IF(K64:K313>0,0,ROW(K64:K313)))))`

Comment: This worked for me on the above example `=AVERAGE(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(A1:A12>0,ROW(A1:A12)),IF(A1:A12>0,0,ROW(A1:A12)))=0,"",FREQUENCY(IF(A1:A12>0,ROW(A1:A12)),IF(A1:A12>0,0,ROW(A1:A12)))))` @Elvis. Remember to CSE the formula!

Comment: seems like there is no difference whether I use CSE or not. The formula for consecutive losses works well but the average consecutive win keeps increasing when the range increase from `K64` to `K313` where the cells from `K77` to `K313`are blank. Is there any other moethid for that?

Comment: Best is to open a new question @Elvis.